# Why does clef not implement ethereum's JSON-RPC

Tags: json-rpc, signature

Assuming that the RPC standard still matches what is to be found today on the [ethereum wiki](https://eth.wiki/json-rpc/API), I was rather surprised to learn that the method calls provided by `clef` do not match the signer methods in the JSON-RPC standard.

That means the signer is not interchangeable with that offered by geth, metamask etc.

What advantage does this bring?